# Printer OKI trap signification (OID)

Tags: snmp, printers, snmp-trap

Someone of you know how find the signification of trap for an OKI printer (B512) ?
I check the manual, and I search on google but I found anything.

Thank you !

Comment: It would have helped if you posted the OID.

That said, if it's not on Google, I doubt anyone will be able to answer. 

I could also question whether this is a question about programming...

Comment: It's about programming implementation because it's a number returned by the printer in SNMP. It was not easy but I ended up finding !

Comment: SNMP is a networking protocol. That doesn't make it a programming question.

Comment: Yes, but it's for an implementation. If you don't need to implement in a application, my question don't have to exist, but is not the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I could find to interpret the return of the printer status in SNMP :

```
okiPrinterOnline = 1,
okiPrinterOffline = 2,
okiNoPrinterAttached = 3,
okiPrinterTonerLow = 4,
okiPrinterPaperOut = 5,
okiPrinterPaperJam = 6,
okiPrinterDoorOpen = 7,
okiPrinterError = 16,
```

Comment: If you edit the question to contain the numeric OID, this answer might be valuable to others. As it is, it gives no information at all to someone searching for that OID in the future.

Comment: I don't understand why do you mean. I give a response of my question with the OID..

Comment: OID as in this definition: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_identifier